# Does syncing gallery means sending all photos to internet?

Tags: security, gallery, samsung-galaxy-s7

I found with fear, that my Gallery on Samsung Galaxy S7 was set up to sync with cloud by default. Does this mean, that all my photos, including secret ones, were silently sended to Samsung??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they are, but in your own Samsung Cloud Account. It is necessary for backup in case you lose/delete these pictures.

Comment: I would like to backup pictures myself, without sending them to big brother. I am very disappointed by such malicious behavior

Comment: Turn Off syncing.

Comment: I couldn't know it syncs. There is no explicit switch for syncing gallery in global settings page, it is hidden inside Gallery application. This is bad will.